# Mapping an arrow from the direct limit of a diagram to the family of arrows from the diagram

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, limits-and-convergence

Consider the direct limit of an indexed family $\{a_n\}_{n\in \omega}$:

$\require{AMScd}$ 
\begin{CD}
a_0     @>>>   \ldots @>>>   a_n     @>>>        a_{n+1} @>>> \ldots\\
@Vi_0VV \ldots @.     \ldots @Vi_nVV @Vi_{n+1}VV \ldots  \\
a       @=     \ldots @=     a       @=          a       @= \ldots
\end{CD}

Let $f:a \to b$ be an arrow from $a$ to $b$.
We can map $f$ to the family of arrows $\{f_n\}_{n\in\omega}$
where $f_n = f\circ i_n$.

E.g. think of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ as the direct limit of $\{\mathbb{R}^n\}_{n\in\omega}$ with arrows 
$(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto (x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n, 0)$
and a function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I am looking for a name to refer to this construction.
Is there a general name for the functor that maps $f$ to $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?
(or some specific instance of this functor e.g. in differential geometry)?
Would it be reasonable to refer to the family $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as "sections" of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The composition of the cone over $a$ with $f$.

In case you are asking how to call the passage from $f : (\sum_i A_i) \to B$ to $(f_i : A_i \to B)_i$, that would be "precomposition with the injections $A_j \to \sum_i A_i$" but you will not like the answer because you are looking for an "established" term. Apparently, category theory is not established enough ;-)

If you do not want to educate your audience and teach them bits of category theory (or type theory) then you could simply call this process **decomposition of $f$**. I suspect "ordinary" mathematicians do not have an established phrase for a very simple reason: ordinary mathematicians do not take coproducts of sets seriously.

Comment: Thanks Andrej, but I am looking for a name that does not refer to the cone since it is kind of fixed and obvious in my case plus my target audience might not know what is a cone. To be more specific, I am looking for what I should call the process of turning a function over $\Sigma^*$ to a family of functions with one for each input size. (I used $\mathbb{R}$ in the question because I felt it would be more familier to others and hoping that there is something like this in geometry).

Comment: I was hoping that if there is a general name then I can search for its examples in other fields and choose something from among their names. ps: maybe it is better to view $a$ as coproduct of the family in place of its direct limit and ask for a name for the restrictions of a function $f$ from $a$ to each member of the family.